# Load datatype dynamically using Springboot @Conditional

Tags: spring-boot, conditional-statements, autowired

I would like to load the database type ( Cassandra or MongoDB) in my Springboot Service class based on some condition. For this, I was planning to use @Conditional annotation mentioned in https://sivalabs.in/2016/03/how-springboot-autoconfiguration-magic/.

In my case, I am extending the org.springframework.stereotype. Repository Interface to create the Repository like below.

In my service class, how can I get the instance of Cassandra Type or Mongo Type based on a profile or configuration in application.yml?

Thanks
Ashish

```
@Repository
public interface CartCassandraRepository extends CrudRepository<com.cassandra.Cart, String> {

}

@Repository
public interface MongoCassandraRepository extends CrudRepository<com.mongo.Cart, String> {

}
```

Here is my com.cassandra.Cart.java

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
@Table("Cart")
public class Cart  {


    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected String id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String userId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    private String productId;
}
```

Here is my com.mongo.Cart.java

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field

@Document(collection = "Cart")
public class Cart  {

    @Id
    protected String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field(value = "UserId")
    private String userId;

    @Field(value = "ProductId")
    private String productId;
}
```

Here's the Service class

```
public class CartServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    CassandraCartRepository cassandraCartRepository;

    @Autowired
    MongoCartRepository mongoCartRepository;

    public Cart save(CartDTO cart){
        // based on configuration or profile load com.mongo.Cart or com.cassandra.Cart
        // based on the configuration or profile do mongoCartRepository.save(cart) or cassandraCartRepository.save(cart)
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need two separate cart class for mongo and cassandra. You can use single class. and annotate fields with both annotations(mongo and cassandra)

Comment: thanks and how will I instantiate the right repository from the service in that case?

Comment: Using a single class and annotating fields with both annotations do not work. The system still tries to load Cassandra configurations and if I exclude CassandraAutoConfiguration from SpringBootApplication, it complains that the cassandraTemplate is not found.